# tikz and commands

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

For some reason I want to mix tikz with commands, but sometimes it doesn't work.

**What works**

If I use `\newcommand{\mycommand}{ultra thick}` it compiles.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mycommand}{ultra thick}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [\mycommand, draw=black, fill=yellow, fill opacity=0.2]
       (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**What doesn't work**

If I use `\newcommand{\mycommand}{fill=yellow}` it doesn't compile.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mycommand}{fill=yellow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [ultra thick, draw=black, \mycommand, fill opacity=0.2]
       (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*Can somebody help me to fix the second example?*

*Maybe there's even a better solution.*

Comment: The information on this question could be useful https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When TikZ encounters a macro it expands and uses its current value as a key. In your case it is `fill=yellow`.

So it looks up a key named `fill=yellow` and of course cannot find but it doesn't check the contents for an equal sign based on the suspicion of *maybe this was meant as a key=value pair*. Hence you need an extra expansion. You can do it via various methods but none of them are as practical as the keys themselves.

Instead use your own styles

```
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={ultra thick, fill=yellow}}
```

This will always work inside other styles. Note that the keys are invented specifically for this reason so that you don't set new macros for everything.